Why is the derivative of $x^x$ not $\ln(x)(x^x)$?
To do this I did $u=x$ and $\frac{dy}{du}=\ln(u)u^x$  and $\frac{du}{dx}=1$ and used the chain rule to get $\ln(x)(x^x)$. A teacher explained that if $f(x)=\exp(g(x))$ then $f'(x)=g'(x)\exp(g(x))$ and used $\exp(\ln(x)x)$. However I do not understand why my method of using the chain rule is incorrect and I do not understand the previous rule either. I have also seen a method using multivariable calculus that I do not understand either.

$u=x$ and therefore $dy/du =d(u^u)/du$, and you have the same issue you had in the beginning.

Thank you, is this result generalised ,i.e. is it not useful to ever use u=x during chain rule substitutions?

No, letting $u=x$ will just recast your problem into the exact same one, with different symbols.

Why isn't it $x^x,$ since $u=x$ means $\frac{d}dx x^u=ux^{u-1}=x^x?$

Substitution doesn't work so blindly in differentiation. By the same reasoning, if $u=x,$ then $$\frac{d}dx(x^2)=\frac{d}dx(ux)=u=x.$$

$\frac{d}{dx} a^x$ is only equal to $a^x \log a$ when $a$ is constant. Here, it isn't, because you have $a=x$.
In general, the formula is $$\left(u^v\right)' = u^v v'\log u + vu^{v-1}u'$$
where  I have used $f'$ to mean the derivative of $f$.
When $u$ is constant, $u'=0$ and this reduces to $u^v v' \log u$. When $v$ is constant, $v'=0$ and it reduces to $vu^{v-1}u'$.

In a comment you asked for a proof of the formula above. I will continue to write $f'$ to mean $\frac d{dx} f$.  In this notation, the product rule says $(uv)' = u'v + uv'$ and the chain rule says that $(f(g))' = g'\cdot f'(g)$.
We will rewrite $u^v$ as $$u^v={\left(e^{\log u}\right)}^v = e^{v\log u}.$$  Then:
$$\begin{align}
\left(u^v\right)' & = \left(e^{v\log u}\right)' \\
& =  e^{v\log u} (v\log u)'& \text{(chain rule and $\left(e^x\right)' = e^x$)} \\
& =  e^{v\log u} \left(v'\log u + v(\log u)'\right)&\text{(product rule)}\\
& =  e^{v\log u} \left(v'\log u + v\frac 1u u' \right)&\text{(chain rule and $(\log x)' = \frac1x$)} \\
& = u^v\left(v'\log u + v\frac 1u u' \right) \\
& = u^v v'\log u + vu^{v-1}u'
\end{align}
$$
Notice that this uses a more general version of exactly the technique your teacher suggested.  Instead of rewriting $x^x$ as $e^{x\log x}$, we are  rewriting $u^v$ as $e^{v\log u}$.

Could you link a proof to the above formula as it looks interesting and I can't find one online?

@wub added one, let me know if you have questions

Thank you very much

The thing is, as $x$ changes, the $u$ doesn't stay constant, which means $\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d u}=\dfrac{\mathrm du^x}{\mathrm dx}$ can't be treated as usual exponential function.
To clearly show what's happening, you'd better write $y,u$ as a function of $x$, then $\dfrac{\mathrm d y(x)}{\mathrm d u(x)}=\dfrac{\mathrm du(x)^x}{\mathrm dx}$ is clearly untrue.
Your teacher's way is right - using logarithms to change exponentials into multiplication is a quite common way to deal with them.

Generalized?
Your calculus textbook probably has a discussion (later in the book) of "chain rule for partial derivatives".
$$
\frac{d}{dx} f(u,v) = \frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u} \frac{du}{dx}
+\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial v} \frac{dv}{dx} .
$$
When you reach have reached that point in your text, try using this formula for $f(u,v) = u^v$ and $u=v=x$.

By the same reasoning, if $y=x\cdot x,$ then letting $u=x,$ $$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(ux)=u=x,$$ when we know the result is $2x.$
If $f(u,v)$ is a "nice enough" function and $y=f(x,x),$ then $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(x,x)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x,x).\tag1$$
In the case of $f(u,v)=u\cdot v,$ both partial derivatives are $x,$ so we get the expected result $2x.$
When $f(u,v)=u^v,$ then the partial derivatives are $f_u(u,v)=v\cdot u^{v-1}$ and $f_v(u,v)=\log u\cdot u^v.$ Then the derivative of $x^x$ is $x^{x}(1+\log x).$
You can see (1) because the definition is:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,x+h)-f(x,x)}{h}$$
And $$ \begin{align}
&\frac{f(x+h,x+h)-f(x,x)}h=\\&\frac{f(x+h,x+h)-f(x,x+h)}h+\frac{f(x,x+h)-f(x,x)}h, \end{align}  $$
In the two fractions on the right, only one variable to $f$ changes, so we then use the mean value theorem for the two terms.
By MVT, $$\frac{f(x+h,x+h)-f(x,x+h)}h=f_u(c,x+h)$$ for some $c$ between $x$ and $x+h.$
Similarly the second term is $f_v(x,d)$ for some $d$ between between $x$ and $x+h.$
If $f_u$ and $f_v$ are continuous, then the limit is $(1).$

You can rewrite $f(x) = x^x$ by $f(x) = e^{\ln(x^x)} = e^{x \ln x}$, now you see that $f(x) = g(h(x))$, where $g(x) = e^x$ and $h(x) = x\ln x$, so we have that
$f'(x) = g'(h(x))\cdot h'(x)$ by the chain rule, and it follows that
$f'(x) = e^{x \ln x}\cdot(\ln x + 1) = e^{\ln x^x}\cdot (\ln x +1) = x^x(\ln x + 1) $.
Another simple way is to use the implicit derivative, as it follows:
$f(x) = x^x$, to simplify notation let's put $y = f(x)$
$y = x^x$
$\ln y = \ln x^x$
$\ln y = x \ln x$
$(\ln y)' = (x \ln x)'$
$ \dfrac{y'}{y} = \ln x + 1$
$ y' = y\cdot (\ln x + 1)$
Now you just put $y = x^x$.
